# MvvmCross 6.2.1 Incompatible target framework

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I've started a new Xamarin project using MvvmCross 6.2.1 which requires netstandard 2.0 or better. However attempting to refernce my PCL project from my iOS project I get an error message claiming that the PCL project has an *Incompatible target framework: .NETCoreApp, version=v2.1*. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Convert your PCL to a .NET Standard project: https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/